# How to understand "{}" sign in below code?

Tags: java, reflection

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
```

Please tell me the code above in "{}" What does it mean?

Comment: did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You create a new implementation (if `TypeToken` is an interface) or extension (if `TypeToken` is a class) inline. In your case the class body is empty, thus `{}`. This concept is known as an **Anonymous Inner Class**.

Comment: @Lechance: Please remember to upvote helpful answers and to accept the best one: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

TypeToken is a class and It's just creating anonymous subclass of `TypeToken` class and invoking `getType()` method from the object in same line. You can split it for simplicity like this,

```
TypeToken<List<String>> typeList = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){};
Type type = typeList.getType();
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#declaring-anonymous-classes) if you are still unfamiliar with declaring anonymous classes.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Lechance I suggest [Accepting one helpful answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

It means empty class body of created TypeToken.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeToken` is an abstract class (only declared as abstract, but don't require to impement any methods), and you inherit it with you anonymous class.
From TypeToken javadocs:

> Capture a generic type with a (usually anonymous) subclass and resolve it against a context class that knows what the type parameters are